# Post To A Users' FB Wall From iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I am working on an app that needs to have a specific function for Facebook.  I simply want to login to Facebook from the app using SSO, pull up a list of friends, and tap on one or more, and click send.  This action would put some message on their wall(s) from this text.  There are so many different tutorials from different sites that add much more functionality than what I need, or are for much older versions of the Facebook SDK.  Could someone give me some guidance in this for the current versions of iOS and Facebook SDKs?

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial. It works perfectly.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/ios-tutorial

Comment: I'm solely using Objective-C, and this seems like an overkill tutorial for simply getting list of friends for a post.

Comment: This is an Objective-C tutorial, and for "simple" getting list of friends you need to handle Facebook login flow and make requests anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess the part where it said to locate a .cpp file threw me as I have only ever worked with .h .m and .xib and haven't seen code formatted like `void FacebookController::ReRequestFriendPermission()` only like `-(void)method`